# Update Approval Response words

Tags: language, approval-process

**Background**: We have a customer that is using the Spanish Language Workbench, so their entire Org is in Spanish.

Issue: When an Approval email is sent to the Approver, one of the OOTB acceptable Spanish responses is 'SÍ' (with the accent) however the user's may/may not have the accent when typing 'Si'. In doing so, the Approval does not go through.

Question: Is there a way to 1) either update the Spanish Workbench language to accept 'Si' without the accent or 2) update the Approval Response answers.

Anyone?

Comment: If you get stuck, I would a) alter the email template that SFDC sends indicating approval is required to mention only the 'good' words that don't require accented characters and/or b) get users to use SF 1 mobile app where approvals are integrated in as notifications into the feed and replying doesn't require typing

Comment: Yes, as a workaround, we did mention to modify the template that goes out to simply use 'Approved', 'Rejected' (in Spanish), however they really need to modify the response word.

Comment: SFDC response words are not customizable AFAIK

Comment: Thanks @cropredy , but I'll leave this question here just in case. :)